# Detect touch event outside of layout

Tags: android, android-event

I'm using an opensource numberpicker I found somewhere (credit to Jeffrey F. Cole) but I just found a bug.

The numberpicker has a handler to increase the number faster when you touch the button

```
long`private Handler repeatUpdateHandler = new Handler();
```

`

```
    class RepetetiveUpdater implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        if (autoIncrement) {
            increment();
            repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RepetetiveUpdater(),
                    REPEAT_DELAY);
        } else if (autoDecrement) {
            decrement();
            repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RepetetiveUpdater(),
                    REPEAT_DELAY);
        }
    }
}

 .....

public class NumberPicker extends LinearLayout {

 .....

    // Auto increment for a long click
    increment.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            autoIncrement = true;
            repeatUpdateHandler.post(new RepetetiveUpdater());
            return false;
        }
    });

    // When the button is released, if we're auto incrementing, stop
    increment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && autoIncrement) {
                autoIncrement = false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is when you longclick the button the counter starts to increase, but when you hold your finger down and drag your finger across the screen the counter keeps adding up, even when you lift your finger.

So how can I detect that the finger gets out of my numberpicker layout and stop the counter?

Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure that's a bug and I'm not even sure it's coming from changes that this number picker made on top of the numberpicker from the API itself. I'm assumings that the buttons that handles incrementing and decrementing the pickers are set up to keep going until an ACTION_UP MotionEvent is received, but this might be over-simplifying it.

**EDIT:**

I've tested this on stock Android 2.3.3 and this is precisely the result.

**EDIT:**

Based on your clarification in the comments, this does sound like a pretty bad bug. Looks like what you need to do is have the Handler removes the callbacks to that runnable in ACTION_UP. Can you link me to the project so I can try to submit a patch?

**EDIT**

The NumberPicker you provided wasn't using Handlers correctly, IMO. Instead of keeping a reference to the same Handler so that callbacks could later be removed, it was created a new one everytime it posted. I've made some changes and fixed the issues here: https://gist.github.com/3657989

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the problem is that when the user lifts his finger anywhere on the screen, the counter keeps adding up unless you lift your finger on the increment button :) If that makes sense..

Comment: I found it here, http://codejeff.com/?p=42, you can find the zip in the second comment. The links in the actual post don't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @just8laze, i just ran the sample and don't see the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @just8laze actually i see the problem now with the decrement button on the bottom left. lemme see if i can fix it real quick.

Comment: @just8laze, here's the fixed class: https://gist.github.com/3657989 Please let me know if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it keeps going until I press the button again. I'm putting my linearlayout in a scrollview, could that cause a problem?

Comment: @just8laze, can you send me your source code for that view and I can check it out?